# CoreParse, BNF Grammar with stack overflow

Tags: objective-c, grammar, cplex, bnf, coreparse

I'm no expert in grammars, but I want to write a CPLEX Parser (which is a LP syntax) in CoreParse [1]. But CoreParse is unable to build the following grammar and exits with a stack overflow instead of an error.
The following is a stripped down example of the syntax, which doesn't work. The String before the @ sign is a name that can be later used to evaluate the parse tree.
'XXX' refers to the specified lexer classes, which are all defined.

```
NSString *expressionGrammar =
@"Complete    ::= dir@<Direction> obj@<ObjExpression> 'Enter';\n"
@"Direction   ::= 'maximize' | 'minimize';\n"
// obj function
@"ObjExpression  ::= term@<ObjTerm> | expr@<ObjExpression> op@<ObjAddOp> term@<ObjTerm> ;\n"
@"ObjTerm        ::= 'Identifier'  | num@<Number> op@<ObjMulOp> 'Identifier' ;\n"
@"ObjAddOp       ::= '+' | '-'; \n"
@"ObjMulOp       ::= '*'; \n"
```

I don't see any problem - does anyone else see why the generation of this grammar makes the generator be stuck in an endless loop?

Thanks,
Mark!

[1] https://github.com/beelsebob/CoreParse